# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Dell XPS 9350 webcam

Tags: 20.04, dell, webcam, xps

I purchased a second-hand Dell XPS 9350 (i5-6ºgen), and I installed the latest Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Everything is working properly except the webcam. I tried all that I know -- enabling the camera in the BIOS, installed `cheese` and `gcuview`. The thing is that I cannot find the file in `/dev/video0`

I do not know if other people have issues with it and how to solve this.

Comment: See [this help page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Dell)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but no solution found on ubuntu 20.04 lts :(